# convert pyspark dataframe value to customized schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am receiving streaming data from Kafka. By default, the dataframe.value is of "string" type. for example, dataframe.value is

```
1.0,2.0,4,'a'
1.1,2.1,3,'a1'
```

The schema of dataframe.value:

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to define a schema on this data frame. The schema I want to get an output:

```
root
 |-- c1: double (nullable = true) 
 |-- c2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- c3: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c4: string (nullable = true)
```

I define the schema and then load the data from kafka but I get error "Kafka has already defined schema can not apply the customized one".

Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the schema when you convert to a data frame.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType
kafkaRdd = sc.parallelize([(1.0,2.0,4,'a'), (1.1,2.1,3,'a1')])
col_types = [DoubleType(), DoubleType(), IntegerType(), StringType()]
col_names = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]
df = kafkaRdd.toDF(col_names, col_types)
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

Here is the output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|1.0|2.0|  4|  a|
|1.1|2.1|  3| a1|
+---+---+---+---+

root
 |-- c1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- c3: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c4: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I receive from streaming and the input data type is string.